# UICollectionView eBay iOS app

Tags: uicollectionviewlayout

I'm pretty new to UICollectionViewController and layout transition stuff.

Currently I'm working on an project that requires layout transition from table view layout to grid layout.

After some exploration, I found that eBay app is using this transition.

![eBay Grid Layout and Transitions]https://i.stack.imgur.com/xouhq.png

As you can see, if you tap on the button at the top right corner, layout can be animated to

![List Layout]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Oxj.png

I'm wondering if anyone knows and can give me some guidelines on how to implement this feature?

P.S. There are totally 3 different kinds of layouts in this app, but I only want the transition from the first image to the second image above.

Thanks a lot!

Frank

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have implemented something very close to eBays app.

Comment: Actually not yet... Wow that's so cool! Could you teach me how to do this if at all possible? You can email me at frankvsense@gmail.com

Comment: I'm happy to help you get to the transition you're looking for, sure. Just pop me a mail with what you have so far or what parts you're stuck with. Once you have it working I'll update this question with an answer for other developers looking for the same thing: tanderza@gmail.com  Cheers

Comment: Can i request this in Swift language?I cant find anywhere.I will be really glad if u import your own layout transition at githud.Thank you,@Tander.

Answer (score 2):

1) Extend a Custom class from UITableViewCell

2) Create a prototype cell and associate it's element via @property or tags (upto you), copy create another prototype cell from the original one, and then just rearrange the content. Hierarchy of elements should remain same(if possible), don't delete/hide element you don't want to show... just push them outside cell boundary. clipSubviews should be checked for the cell.

3)Overrides in CustomCell

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if(self.frame.size.width == 320) { //Based on frame size you set in storyboard

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            self.<element>.frame = CGRectMake<copy frame values from storyboard for list layout> 

        }];

    } else {

         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            self.<element>.frame = CGRectMake<copy frame values from storyboard for grid layout>

        }];

    }

}
```

4) In collection view delegate have these methods

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(isGridLayout) {

            return CGSizeMake(160, 160);

        } else {

            return CGSizeMake(320, 90);

        }

    return CGSizeZero;
}



-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UICollectionViewCell *cell;

        if(isGridLayout)

            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GridCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        else

            cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;

    }
```

5) For switching layouts:

```
-(IBAction)swapViewLayout:(UIButton*)sender {
    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];
    isGridLayout = sender.isSelected;
    NSIndexPath * topItem = [self.productCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 80 + self.productCollectionView.contentOffset.y)];
    if(!topItem)
        return;
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]-2 inSection:0]]];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:topItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

eBay must have implemented this using springs and struts at the cell level rather than using auto layout. If you turn on the UIViewShowAlignmentRects, the alignment rects upon setCollectionViewLayout, it does not interpolate the itemSize change using auto layout. With the code below, you have to turn off auto layout in MyCollectionViewCell.xib

```
class MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var photo : UIImageView!    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
        self.photo.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
    }
}
```

I tried self.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true) with auto layout but since the alignment rects don't interpolate already, the cell simply won't transform nicely. Maybe this will change in iOS 9 around the corner?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at my 
[github](https://github.com/tylerlantern/IOS_CollectionViewTransition). I combined Edgardo's answer to complete my work. I put his code inside cell's init method.
Here is my scenario.

1. Create custom cell that can manipulate subviews corresponding a layout.
2. override apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) with self.layoutIfNeeded(). The method is called when a layout is about to change. So call self.layoutIfNeeded() to apply its subview to rearrange imidiately.
3. Once a cell call layoutIfNeeded(). layoutSubviews is called. Put a method for rearranging its subview
4. Call collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout with ur custom layout.In my sample project. I do have 3 layout so I instantiate 3 layout. and toggle them respectively.